# Simulate paste action in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate an excel spreadsheet using VBA (is actually something different using a COM server but it is the same syntax). Thisis a report generated that I want to write in Excel for formatting and presentation purpose. CSV exports and other techniques are out of the equation because of the technology involved.

So, I am able to do it writing each value in each cell, but it is painfully slow, so, I decided I could write a bunch of values at once (let's say 250 records each time). So I store those values delimited by a carriage return and if I copy/paste that using VBA it works perfectly.

Problem is, I can't use the clipboard (as the report is executed many times simultaneously), so can I simulate the paste action (or some other similar) from a list of values in Excel without using the clipboard?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to copy values in VBA I know is

```
Range("destrange") = Range("srcrange")
```

`destrange` and `srcrange` should be the same size. Also no formatting data etc. will be copied.

edit: here is something that could be [usefull](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306022/).

Comment: Hi, I couldn't use copy a range, but the link show several options, importing text files was the way to go in my case.
Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of `Variant`s and assign it to a range:

```
  Dim v() As Variant

  ReDim v(1 To 20, 1 To 10)
  'Fill v
  v(5, 5) = 42
  '...

  Range("a1:j20").Value = v
```

Comment: It is a very good option, but in my environment I couldn't define a Variant variable.